# Lightning component is not updating the field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-data-service

I am trying to make use of LDS in the lightning component to change the status of the case like below

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global"  >
 <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="form" 
        objectApiName="Case" 
        recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}">
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="statusInput" fieldName="Status" class="slds-hide" />
        <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" label="Close" />
  </lightning:recordEditForm>   
</aura:component>
```

And the controller is like

```
({
    handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();      
        var fields = event.getParam('fields');
        fields.Status = 'Closed';
        component.find('form').submit(fields); 
    }
})
```

When clicking on the button nothing happens.I tried to debug and I dont see any errors there either

[image]

Can anyone suggest me why I am not able to see any changes on the status.

Comment: you can try console.log(JSON.stringify(fields)); to see the data coming in fields. What is the issue now ? Is case not getting updated with Closed status ?

Comment: Yeah the status is not being updated to Closed

Comment: @brahmajitammana I see `{"Status":"Closed"}` when I log the fields

Comment: Is your quesiton answered then ?

Comment: @brahmajitammana Nope. When I log fields `console.log(JSON.stringify(fields)); ` I see `{"Status":"Closed"}` in the log.  but the component is not updating the Case Status to be closed

Comment: can you add <lightning:messages /> to see if there is any error ? also look at the debug log ,you will find something if any trigger is overriding this update. I did a quick test with your code and seems to be working in my org.